# Netbeans, git, cant clone repository

Tags: git, netbeans, ssh

I joined a new team at work and they using git to store their project. Via netbeans I have tried to clone repository using ssh and valid user/pass, but I stil get this error:

`java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`

Have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Try cloning it using the git tool itself.

Comment: It's easier to debug the command line first. Make `git clone` in the shell working first, as a sanity check, after that you can try to debug what's happening in netbeans.

Comment: Your problem is the network. Netbeans/git client tried to connect to git repo but could not get the TCP connection. Check firewalls/vpn first. I hope you resolved it by now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ssh doesn't require a user/password.

If you have a username/password, you should clone your repo by usinh an https:// url, not an ssh one.

If you only have an ssh url, you must be sure to have the proper public/private keys in place in [`Team > Git > Clone` wizard](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/git.html#github)

Cloning using a git distribution in command line can also help getting a more precise error message.